# Maximize not working in different resolutions in JFrame with JTattoo

Tags: java, swing

I have problem in JFrame maximize state with JTattoo.**It works fine without JTattoo**.
Sample code will show below,

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MyFrame
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
  {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.graphite.GraphiteLookAndFeel");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("My Frame");
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  }
}
```

**Issue Reproducible scenario :**

1. Run the code
2. Minimize the window
3. Reduce the screen resolution
4. Restore the Frame by clicking the task bar icon

**Result :**
JFrame not set to the screen bounds.Can't see the frame buttons.**But this works fine without JTattoo**

Comment: works for me in Java6/7 in WinXP/8

Comment: Still i have the problem.Hope you tried with JTattoo.First need to run in higher resolution.Then need to minimize.Change the resolution to lower one.Restore the frame clicking the task bar icon.Frame go beyond the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a way to do it.Functionally it works fine.Any one with good knowledge about swing please comment or improve my work.**

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class MyFrame
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ParseException
  {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.graphite.GraphiteLookAndFeel");


    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame")
    {

      @Override
      public Rectangle getMaximizedBounds()
      {
        Insets screenInsets = getToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
        Rectangle screenSize = getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
        Rectangle maxBounds = new Rectangle(screenInsets.left + screenSize.x, screenInsets.top + screenSize.y,
            screenSize.x + screenSize.width - screenInsets.right - screenInsets.left, screenSize.y + screenSize.height
                - screenInsets.bottom - screenInsets.top);
        return maxBounds;
      }

    };

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("My Frame GUI Example");
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final IconizeWindowState state= new IconizeWindowState();

    frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
      @Override
      public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent we)
      {
        //System.out.println("Old State = " + we.getOldState());
        //System.out.println("New State = " + we.getNewState());
        //System.out.println("################################");
        int oldState = we.getOldState();
        int newState = we.getNewState();
        //Check weather window iconized from maximize state or not.
        if (oldState != Frame.NORMAL)
        {
          if ((oldState & Frame.ICONIFIED) == 0 && (newState & Frame.ICONIFIED) != 0)
          {
            //System.out.println("Frame was iconized");
            frame.setMaximizedBounds(null);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
            //window iconized from maximize state.
            state.iconizeFromMaximizedState = true;
          }
        }

        if ((oldState & Frame.ICONIFIED) != 0 && (newState & Frame.ICONIFIED) == 0)
        {
          if (state.iconizeFromMaximizedState)
          {
            //System.out.println("Frame was deiconized");
            frame.setMaximizedBounds(frame.getMaximizedBounds());
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            state.iconizeFromMaximizedState = false;
          }
        }

      }
    });

  }
}

class IconizeWindowState
{
  boolean iconizeFromMaximizedState = false;
}
```